# Why bluetooth so bad on windows 10?

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth

- I turn on my pc
- Bluetooth already on
- I go to my bluetooth settings
- Audio device is not connected, but is paired. I press connect to device
- Why in the world is not paired already? but lets go on (can we fix this?)
- I press the sound icon on windows... but that device is not there. Boomer

How to fix

- Disable bluetooth
- Enable bluetooth
- Connect to the device (of course cant auto connect)
- Now I hear on the device a sound that means somebody paired (I didnt hear the first time)
- Now I can choose the device in the sound panel

How can I improve this flow because is super annoying.

Comment: What devices? What version of Windows? How do you receive/send the Bluetooth signal? What have you tried to change your workflow?

Comment: Bluethooth harman karman aura 2. Windows 10 Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362. How many ways are there to receive bluetooth signals, as far as I know there is only 1 way. How else can i change my workflow?

Comment: Dongles, antennas, on board or as an addon card. One of those options does have to exist on your PC. What have you tried? You know that one works so you probably know a couple that don't. Which ones are those? For instance just turn off Bluetooth from the get go and turn it back on.

Comment: Because of WinRT. Fix - use any legacy OS that does not use WinRT for system tasks.

Comment: @Seth I only have an integrated bluetooth on the motherboard. In my original question I'm only talking about this single bluetooth antenna. I have no other way to connect to bluetooth.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I'm using Windows 10 Version 10.0.18362 Build 18362 - Not sure how can I fix with the information you provided.

Comment: You can't because its MS bugs.

Comment: I mean, it works, but I need to do all the steps. So its normal for everyone? that can be true..